# Why is my for loop not exiting?

Tags: java

First time working with arrays. I think I've figure out the beginning of establishing the array but I'm having a problem with one of my loops not kicking out and I don't why. My loop of "days" keeps restarting after hitting 10. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class TempArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sumOfTemps = 0.0;
        double [] temperatures = new double[10];        
        for(int index = 0; index <= 10; index++){
            for(int days = 1; days <= 10; days++){
                System.out.print("Enter the temperature for day " + days + " : ");
                temperatures[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
                sumOfTemps = sumOfTemps + temperatures[index];
```

Comment: no one can tell, we dont see the entire body of the loop

Comment: You're running through the 'days' loop 10 times because of the 'index' loop. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: try for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++){

Comment: I saw 11*11 = 121 keyboard.nextDouble(); and after the 10*11 = 110, you get an ArrayOutOfBoundException : temperatures[10] does not exist

Comment: assuming the three lines shown are the entire code, the `days` loop will repeat `10` time and the 11th time will end with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your array has only the length of `10` which means valid index range is `[0, 9]` and index goes till equal `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will end, but because of first loop you start second loop 10 times. So you have to type 100 temperatures.

I don't know that you are trying to achieve, but if you want to provide only 10 temperatures, get rid of the first loop and leave only the second one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my 2nd comment, you probably want something like this:

```
for(int days = 0; days < 10; days++) {
    System.out.print("Enter the temperature for day " + (days+1) + " : ");
    temperatures[day] = keyboard.nextDouble();
    sumOfTemps = sumOfTemps + temperatures[day];
}
```